# Composer on Amazon Server ec2 - autoload not working

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I configured an Amazon Cloud server, installed php, apache, etc.   Then installed composer and ran `$php composer.phar` and its working.

But when I tried to include the vendor/autoload.php file (which I can clearly see on the server), I get this warning and fatal error because it can't seem to find the file:

> Warning: require(/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open  stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/index.php on line 12
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/index.php on line 12

Line 12 is simply:

```
require "/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Does anybody know what is causing this error or anything that would help eliminate the error?  Thanks.

Comment: Go to root of your laravel project and update your composer using `composer.phar update`.

Comment: Thanks..I'm not running a laravel project (of course, I may not know what that means).  In other words, will composer only work if the file calling autoload is in a certain folder?

Comment: Ok.. This error shows that autoload.php file is not available at require path. This file is framework dependent and will be generated automatically. This depends on framework also. Can you tell me which framework you are using.

Comment: I was trying to use dompdf which they say you can get through composer. Thanks

Comment: Just check whether your autoload.php file exists in `/home/ec2-user/vendor/autoload.php`. Also check your permission for the file. Apache should be able to read it in your /home dir.

Comment: when I run if (file_exists (path/to/autoload.php)) it does exist and permission are set to 0777

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, here are the steps i followed to solve it:

1. Install composer as described in: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/getting-started/installation.html
2. Copy all composer components under www root
3. Change ownership of composer components to apache
4. If you are using an ini file for the AWS credentials, place it under /.aws (under the root folder)

Here are the steps:

```
cd ~
mkdir composer
cd composer
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar require aws/aws-sdk-php
sudo cp -r ~/composer /var/www/html
sudo chown -R apache:apache /var/www/html/composer
sudo mkdir /.aws
```

Don't forget to copy the credentials file to ./aws.
You can also restrict read access to the credentials file to apace only:

```
sudo chown apahce:apache ./aws/credentials
sudo chmod 440 ./aws/credentials
```

Finally, update the required statement in the php file. In the example above i placed composer in its own folder so the reference would be:

```
require 'composer/vendor/autoload.php';
```